# Differentiation under integral sign - NON LEBESGUE measure

Tags: measure-theory

On page 22 of this document

http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Lectures/pmall.pdf

we find a (Theorem 3.5.1) a useful theorem concerning differentiation under integral signs (where we don't necessarily use Lebesgue measure).

Does anyone know a good (book) reference for this result?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: folland real an.

Comment: Are you interested in a proof for 'simple sets' $U$ and $E$?